# Laravel 5.4 Passport: Modal Login

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.4, laravel-passport

I am new to laravel and I am trying to use a modal to let users login to a website.

I set up laravel passport as described here in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport).

Now if I am entering the credentials of an existing user I get back a access_token, BUT what to do next? I am struggling to figure out how to set the user as logged in.

Comment: Passport is intended for API credentials, I think you are saying you want just regular login to your website.

Comment: I also got a regular login working. But I am trying to set up a modal login for users

Comment: A modal is just CSS, it does not change anything about how you should login? I see no relation between a modal and the use of Passport!

Comment: The modal is not the problem. I want to login users by getting them logged in through the api